# Invalid conditional statement being run

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am a beginner but I am trying to be ambitious and start to learn by creating a text-based game with varying difficulties. I plan on achieving varying difficulties by making use of random values as the scope of my knowledge in programming is limited.

However, I encountered a problem wherein my elif condition inside the difficulty function is always met even though it's seemingly invalid. I am also open for corrections in my code and also suggestions on what I can learn to improve my project. Thank you!

```
import time
import math
import random

print("BLAZE")
time.sleep(1)
print("Welcome, user. Please tell me your name.")
name = input("Name: ")
print("Welcome,", name, ".")
time.sleep(3)

def difficulty(): 
    print("Please set your difficulty.")
    print("Difficulty levels:")
    print("1 - Expert difficulty: Countries are enveloped in irreparable poverty and relies on war to gain power.")
    print("2 - Challenging difficulty: Your land must be wary of other countries.")
    print("3 - Easy difficulty: Other countries are pleased to make friends rather than war.")
    diff = input("Difficulty: ")
    while diff != "1" or "2" or "3":
        if diff == "1":
            cf1 = input("Confirm difficulty. Yes or No?")
            if cf1 == "Yes":
                print("Understood.")
                time.sleep(1)
                print("Starting game...")
                start(diff)
            if cf1 == "No":
                difficulty()
        if diff == "2":
            cf2 = input("Confirm difficulty. Yes or No?")
            if cf2 == "Yes":
                print("Understood.")
                time.sleep(1)
                print("Starting game...")
                start(diff)
            if cf2 == "No":
                difficulty()
        if diff == "3":
            cf3 = input("Confirm difficulty. Yes or No?")
            if cf3 == "Yes":
                print("Understood.")
                time.sleep(1)
                print("Starting game...")
                start(diff)
            if cf3 == "No":
                difficulty()
        elif diff != "1" or "2" or "3":
            print("Invalid Answer.")
            difficulty()

def start(diff):
    print("Expert difficulty.")
    print("Good morning.")

def start(diff):
    print("Challenging difficulty.")
    print("Good morning.")

def start(diff):
    print("Easy difficulty.")
    print("Good morning.")

difficulty()
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack and thanks for the question. For advice, you should try not to repeat your code. There's a lot of repetition in code for the different outcomes of diff. Also, I think you can do without the while loop.

Answer (score 1):

The expression `a = diff != "1" or "2" or "3"` evaluate always to True since the string "2" and "3" evaluates True. This is because the operator `!=` applies only to the string "1".
You should either do:

```
elif diff != "1" or diff != "2": # no need to check for != "3" because we are in the else
```

However you can better do a chain of if-elif, so that you check each condition only once.

```
if diff == "1":
  ...
elif diff == "2":
  ...
elif diff == "3":
  ...
else:
  print("Invalid Answer.")
  difficulty()
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want to say `elif diff != "1" and diff != "2" and diff != "3":`. The problem lies in your `or` statement. In python if you use a not empty string as a condition it always returns `True`, the same apply for non empty `list` and `dict` as well:

```
if "2":
    print("not empty string")
if '':
    print("empty string")

if ["aaa"]:
    print("not empty list")
if []:
    print("empty list")

if {"a" : 1}:
    print("not empty dict")
if {}:
    print("empty dict")
```

Output:

```
not empty string
not empty list
not empty dict
```

The `or` statement means returning `True` if any of condition satisfies.

Answer (score 0):

Your condition for `elif` is always true. Your asking Python if string `"2"` or string `"3"` exist, which they do. You are *not* asking for the value of the variable.

Try:

```py
>>> if "1":
...     print("True")
```

and

```py
>>> i = "1"
>>> if i == "1":
...     print("True")
```

The first condition checks if the string exists, the second one checks for the value of the variable.

Refactoring the whole if-statement, your code should look something like this:

```py
if diff == "1":
    # Your code
elif diff == "2":
    # Your code
elif diff == "3":
    # Your code
else:
    print("Invalid Answer.")
    difficulty()
```

Comment: Must I remove the while loop?

Comment: I think the code is working without the while loop.